# Passed parameter is undefined in a function, and in the callback. Defined elsewhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm sure theres something silly that I'm overlooking here, but thanks in advance.

I'm trying to pass a prop to my fetch. The `location.param1` shows up fine, while the same thing inside the fetchData() call shows as undefined. Even when called after the initial showed as defined.

Heres the code...

```
    fetchData = (name) => {
    console.log(name)
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            pokemon: {
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
                sprites: data.sprites,
                abilities: data.abilities,
                base_experience: data.base_experience,
                forms: data.forms,
                game_showings: data.game_indices,
                held_items: data.held_items,
                moves: data.moves,
                stats: data.stats,
                types: data.types,
                weight: data.weight,
                height: data.height
            }
        }), console.log(this.state.pokemon))
}

render() {

    const { location } = this.props;


    return (
        <div >
            {location.param1}
            {this.fetchData(location.param1)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you fetching data or setting state in your render function? It should be done outside it using a lifecycle method.

Comment: You’re calling `fetchData` inside render and emitting the result? There are several issues here, including 1) `fetchData` is asynchronous so there’s nothing renderable coming back, 2) `fetchData` isn’t returning anything renderable anyway, 3) calling `fetchData` eventually calls `setState`, which will trigger another render, which will call fetchData, which will call setState, which will trigger a render… You should be using lifecycle methods or hooks to kick off the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

i cant'see where are you fetching param1 from your json (i think).
Anyway you should not call a fetch inside the render.

You can use React Hooks (see here => https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) in order to simplify the code.

f.e:

```
     function Foo () {
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);

            //GET   

            async function getData() {  
            const res = await fetch("http://yourURL");  
            const data = await res.json();  
            setData(data);      
            }

            //UseEffect

            useEffect(() => {   
            getData();  
            }, []);


            //...inside return()

            return(
            {data
              //if you want to filter for a spec id 
              .filter(({ id }) => id === 0)
              //go through data                 
              .map(pokemon => (             
                <yourComponent            
                  key={pokemon.id}  
                  name={pokemon.name}   
                  sprites={pokemon.prites}  
                  ...   
                />  
              ))}
             )
            }
    export default Foo
```

Hope it helps!